# Could someone explain the keyword "this" to me?

Tags: java, this

I'm able to learn and pick up things very fast, but this is still confusing me:

This is in the main class (DCFlags):

```
private WGCustomFlagsPlugin pluginWGCustomFlags;
private WorldGuardPlugin pluginWorldGuard;
private DCPvPToggle pluginDCPvPToggle;
private RegionListener listener;

public WGCustomFlagsPlugin getWGCFP(){
    return this.pluginWGCustomFlags;
}

public WorldGuardPlugin getWGP() {
    return this.pluginWorldGuard;
}

public DCPvPToggle getPPT(){
    return this.pluginDCPvPToggle;
}

public void onEnable(){
    this.pluginWorldGuard = Utils.getWorldGuard(this);
    this.pluginWGCustomFlags = Utils.getWGCustomFlags(this);
    this.pluginDCPvPToggle = Utils.getDCPvPToggle(this);
    this.listener = new RegionListener(this);
}
```

This in a different class (Utils):

```
public static WGCustomFlagsPlugin getWGCustomFlags(DCFlags plugin){
    Plugin wgcf = plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WGCustomFlags");
    if ((wgcf == null) || (!(wgcf instanceof WGCustomFlagsPlugin))) {
        return null;
    }
    return (WGCustomFlagsPlugin)wgcf;
}

public static WorldGuardPlugin getWorldGuard(DCFlags plugin){
    Plugin wg = plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("WorldGuard");
    if ((wg == null) || (!(wg instanceof WorldGuardPlugin))) {
        return null;
    }
    return (WorldGuardPlugin)wg;
}

public static DCPvPToggle getDCPvPToggle(DCFlags plugin){
    Plugin ppt = plugin.getServer().getPluginManager().getPlugin("DCPvPToggle");
    if ((ppt == null) || (!(ppt instanceof DCPvPToggle))) {
        return null;
    }
    return (DCPvPToggle)ppt;
}
```

I know this is for being able to use methods from other plugins, but what is "this." for and why is it needed?

Answer (score 4):

`this` is always a reference to the current object.

In these examples it's not needed. However, consider the following:

```
class C {

    private String name;

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

}
```

In this case, the `this` keyword serves to differentiate between the *local variable* `name`, passed to the `setName` method, and the *field* `this.name`, which is declared in the class.

Also consider the following:

```
class C {

    private String name;

    public void doSomething(final String name) {
        // here, `this` is an instance of C
        new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                // here, `this` is an instance of Runnable

                System.out.println(name);
                    // prints the name passed to the method

                System.out.println(this.name);
                    // error: Runnable has no field name

                System.out.println(C.this.name); 
                    // prints the enclosing class's name
            }
        }.run();
    }
}
```

In some other languages, such as Python, it is always required to use `self.` (the rough semantic equivalent of `this.`) to refer to a field. In Java, it is not.

Comment: One correction. It's not *always* a reference to the current object. It can also be used to denote a constructor of the current class.

Comment: Another correction: in python things works slightly differently, there is no keyword referring to the current object, but for a class each method's first argument is a reference to the current object. i.e. you can always do `class Foo: def bar(this, x): this.x = x` in python, even though the *convention* is to use self.

Comment: @zmo exactly; that's why I put "rough semantic equivalent" because that's how it's typically used, but you're right that `self` isn't actually a keyword. I've always wondered why Python uses `self` instead of the traditional `this`, when either would work and the latter would be less confusing to C-type programmers...

Comment: @TheodorosChatzigiannakis as in `this()` or `this(0)`? Yes, true, but I see that as a completely different usage of the keyword. One behaves like a method/constructor and the other behaves like an object. Same for `super`: you can have `class C extends S { C() { super(); }` in which case `super()` is like a method/constructor, but in `@Override public void paintComponent(Graphics g) { super.paintComponent(g); }` it's acting more like an object on which you're invoking a method rather than a method itself.